# How to use auto_import feature with FreeMarker and maven or ant (not servlet)

Tags: freemarker, templating

I'd like to test using freemarker to automatically build my html files at compile time (not use the servlet) and want to use the auto_import feature so I don't have to re define the template for each file.  I can either use ANT or Maven.  How do you use the auto_import feature to automatically load templates within FreeMarker using either ANT or Maven?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`auto_imports` is just one of the many FreeMarker settings, and it has nothing to do with servlets, Maven or Ant. So if you can process the files with Ant or Maven (one way is using the Maven FMPP plugin or the Ant FMPP task), then you should be able to use use `auto_imports` as well.

**Update:** There's an issue with FMPP (until 0.9.15 is released): it doesn't know this setting, so you can't set it through FMPP. But instead it has "Header and footer choosing", which is even more flexible. See: http://fmpp.sourceforge.net/settings.html

Comment: Where do you set auto_import?  Can you set it in config.fmpp?  I only found an example on how to set it using web.xml and need another example.

Comment: Indeed, FMPP doesn't expose this particular FreeMarker setting, as it didn't exist back then. However, for the same reason FMPP has its own non-FreeMarker setting to address the same problem, and it's even more flexible; see "Header and footer choosing" on http://fmpp.sourceforge.net/settings.html#sect8

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [FMPP](http://fmpp.sourceforge.net/)?

> FMPP is a general-purpose text file preprocessor tool that uses FreeMarker templates.

It can be used via command-line or Ant and might provide all the features you need.

Comment: I'm using fmpp-maven-plugin which is a maven plugin front-end for FMPP.  How do you set auto_import using FMPP via ant?  Can you set it in the config.fmpp?